# Writing point type geometry using ArcPy gives TypeError: expect single error

Tags: arcpy, point, geometry, typeerror

Through the following script, I want to write a point feature:

```
import arcpy

coordinates = [(323528, 6293203)]

PATH =   r"C:\Test"
SHAPE =  "PM.shp"

# Create a feature class with a spatial reference of GCS WGS 1984
result = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(PATH, SHAPE, "POINT", spatial_reference = 24879)
feature_class = result[0]

# Write feature to new feature class
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(feature_class, ['SHAPE@']) as cursor: cursor.insertRow([coordinates])
```

However, when I run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SCRIPT", line 13, in <module>
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(feature_class, ['SHAPE@']) as cursor: cursor.insertRow([coordinates])
TypeError: expect single [X,Y[,Z[,M]]]
```

I used this same script to create a polygon with four vertices, but apparently it doesn't work to create a point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this involves Point Geometry, simply changing the shape token ("SHAPE@XY" instead of "SHAPE@") negates the need to create an intermediate ArcPy Point.  Also, since the point coordinates are already wrapped in a list, they don't need to be double-wrapped in a list with the insert cursor (*this was the cause of the original error*).

```py
import arcpy

coordinates = [(323528, 6293203)]

PATH =   r"C:\Test"
SHAPE =  "PM.shp"

# Create a feature class with a spatial reference of GCS WGS 1984
result = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(PATH, SHAPE, "POINT", spatial_reference = 24879)
feature_class = result[0]

# Write feature to new feature class
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(feature_class, ['SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
    cursor.insertRow(coordinates)
```

Note, for Point Geometry passing coordinates directly to "SHAPE@" will work, I recommend using "SHAPE@XY" to be more explicit that coordinates are being passed to the insert cursor.

Answer (score 2):

See below, code is commented. You need to create a Point first, add it to a Python list/tuple, and then use the insert cursor. You also do not need the feature_class = result[0]

```
import arcpy

## coordinates
x = 323528
y = 6293203

## create a Point Geometry
pt = arcpy.Point(x, y)

## set for output
PATH =   r"C:\Test"
SHAPE =  "PM.shp"

# Create a feature class with a spatial reference of GCS WGS 1984
feature_class = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(PATH, SHAPE, "POINT", spatial_reference = 24879)

## the row to insert, must be a sequence eg list/tuple etc
insert_row = [pt]

# Write feature to new feature class
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(feature_class, ['SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    cursor.insertRow(insert_row)
```